# Retropie SDL Key not recognized warning

Tags: raspbian, retropie, sdl

I have a RPi 3B with Retropie 4.1 all updated to the latest binaries. I had installed minecraft from the RetroPie-Setup and since then I am getting SDL warnings logged into the console that read "The key you just pressed is not recognized by SDL... EVDEV Keycode ###". The keycodes appear to be mapped to the buttons on the Wii U Pro Controller I'm using. I was not getting the SDL warnings prior to installing minecraft.

I have updated Emulation Station from source, which reinstalls SDL 2.0.5+1rpi

The system seems to be functioning just fine, however those annoying messages appear for a second when launching roms, or litter the console when exiting ES. Games and control in ES function as expected, so it seems just superficial.

Does anyone know how to fix, or at least suppress these messages?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there must have been a bug in this version (2.0.5+1rpi). After updating again recently, SDL has been upgraded to 2.0.5+3rpi and the issue is no longer happening.